# setTimeOut and local function

Tags: x++, axapta

I'm working on Ax 4.0

I'm trying to use the Object.setTimeOut method in a job with a local function, as stated in the [msdn documentation :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa857865%28v=ax.10%29)

```
static void setTimeOutJob()
{
    Object o = new Object();

    void printText()
    {
        ;
        info( "2 seconds has elapsed since the user did anything" );
    }
    ;
    // Set a Time Out with the idle flag set to false
    o.setTimeOut(identifierstr(printText), 2000, false);
}
```

But this simple job doesn't produce anything, so it seems I'm missing something here.

Has someone worked with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setTimeout` method does not work with a local function in a job.

For a working example have a look on the form `tutorial_Timer` instead.

**Update:**

The `setTimeout` method is a "magic" function, but it does not turn AX into a multithreading environment.

It only works while a Windows [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) is in action. In the AX context it means that a form is running and someone else is waiting for the form to complete. The `sleep` function does not meet the criteria.

Also the object must be "alive", calling a garbage collected object is no good!

Example (class based):

```
class SetTimeoutTest extends Object //Yes, extend or it will not compile
{
    str test;
}

public void new()
{
    super();
    test = "Hello";
}

public str test()
{
    return test;
}

protected void timedOut()
{;
    test = "2 seconds has elapsed since the user did anything";
    info(test);
}

static void main(Args args)
{
    SetTimeoutTest t = new SetTimeoutTest();
    FormRun fr;
    ;
    t.setTimeOut(methodStr(SetTimeoutTest,timedOut), 2000, false);
    //sleep(4000); //Does not work
    fr = ClassFactory::formRunClassOnClient(new Args(formstr(CustGroup))); //Could be any form
    fr.init();
    fr.run();
    fr.wait(); //Otherwise the t object runs out of scope
    info(t.test());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just don't think it works with jobs.  I've used it on forms where the method is on the element level, and have done element.setTimeout and it works fine.

Comment: Then the documentation is misleading. I already used setTimeout in a form, but in this case using it in a job (which is only for test purpose) with a local function would have made things easier. Right now I can't even get it to work in a class.

Comment: I think the object has to be "alive" in order for the `setTimeOut` to work.

Comment: But I share your problem, it does not seem to work with a class!

Comment: I think the purpose is for forms when you click a button, they have a few moments to cancel perhaps?

Comment: @JanB You are right, the issue comes from the object's lifetime.
If I declare my class in a form's class declaration, `setTimeOut` works fine on it (as long as my form is opened of course).

I was hoping to use `setTimeOut` in a Thread Manager class, for monitoring thread status.
I will seek another solution if I can not do it without a form.