# Threading AX 2012

Tags: multithreading, serial-port, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm having trouble with AX 2012, my point is that I must interface a RS-232 scale in Dynamics.

I've got working discrete mode (open port, take current weight, close port) so COM port config is fine.

My problem is when implementing continuous mode (read continuously from port, and do the logic to weight multiple items, without user having to click on  anything), while i'm reading port, the UI is frozen, even can't click a button to stop the process.

My question is: can this be done with another thread not blocking the main (UI) thread?

I was reading the documentation and can't find anything in clear. IMHO, I think that doing it all in only one thread won't do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

AX is not multi-threaded, so the obvious answer is: no.

However AX does support "polling" calls called from the event loop (in a form). Use the [setTimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/object.settimeout.aspx) method which is available on all objects.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359271/settimeout-and-local-function) for a working example.

This may work for you, if you can do a non blocking call to test whether there is any data.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create separate threads in Ax, however it's rarely done and not advisable. Google 'Ax 2012 Thread MSDN' for info.

In my opinion you'd be better off creating a service in C# that handles the nuts and bolts of communicating via the COM port, and using the Business Connector to read/write records when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way to achieve this continous processing is creating a batch job that runs on a periodic basis. You can run more than one processing task from a single batch job execution, and you can create this tasks programmatically from the single job execution, so that you can simulate multithread this way with good performance:

An example:

http://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axilicious/archive/2012/02/24/business-operation-framework-and-multi-threading.aspx